# How to use get/set methods with text input inside ui-grid cell

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ui-grid

I have a column with editable cells. The cell displays an operator like ">" "<" or "=". But the data model represents this with 0, 1, 2 and so on.

So I need a way to convert the data from it's numeric representation to it's operator counterpart when displayed, and then I need to convert it back when saving the data.

After looking around a little bit it seems like using a get/set function with the ng-model is the way to do it. But I can't get it right. There are very few examples of this online.

My cell template looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
   <input type="text" class="sample form-control" ng-model="row.entity.operator" ng-model-getter-setter="get=grid.appScope.listCtrl.getOperator(row.entity.operator);set=grid.appScope.listCtrl.setOperator(row.entity.operator)">
</div>
```

But it doesn't do anything. The cell just displays the ng-model value. As I said I couldn't even find a good example online where they use get and set functions, so any help would be much appreciated!

I'll include the get and set function as well:

```
public getOperator(operator: string): string {
        switch (operator) {
            case "0": {
                return "";
            }
            case "1": {
                return ">";
            }
            case "2": {
                return "<";
            }              
            case "3": {
                return "=";
            }
            default: {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
    public setOperator(operator: string): string {
        switch (operator) {
            case "": {
                return "0";
            }
            case ">": {
                return "1";
            }
            case "<": {
                return "2";
            }
            case "=": {
                return "3";
            }
            default: {
                return "0";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20306%20Custom%20Filters), describing how to use cellfilter to apply an Angular filter to your values.

Comment: Looking through it they seem to do something in the for-loop after fetching the data, but not in the cell template. Going through the data and converting it manually is what I'm currently doing, and it works. I'm just looking for a prettier solution :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: The for-loop is used to modify the data (it contains gender as 'male'/'female', changed into '1'/'2') so the workings of the filter can be demonstrated. In the columnDef the cellFilter is set to 'mapGender', which is the Angular filter used to map the '1'/'2' back to 'male'/'female' (not the most exhilarating example to be honest ;).
In your case there could be a mapOperator filter doing something like that.